# Power series expansion of a function under the integral sign

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have the following integral:
$$S(x)=\int_a^bdtK(x,t)g(t)$$
I don't know the function $g(t)$, but I know it's continuous in the $[a,b]$, so, for the Heine Cantor theorem it's uniformly continuous in $[a,b]$. Is it this information a sufficient condition to write:
$$S(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k\int_a^bK(x,t)t^k$$ where the $a_k$ are obviously unknown coefficients? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not sufficient. Being uniformly continuous is *very* far from being represented by a power series. For example, the function $g(t)=|t|$ on $[-1,1]$ cannot be represented by a power series.

To give a concrete  example, consider $K(x,t) = H(x-t)$ (Heaviside function). Then $$\int_a^b K(x,t)t^k = \int_a^x t^k\,dt = \frac{1}{k+1}(x^{k+1}-a^{k+1})$$
so from your formula with $a_k$  you end up concluding that $S$ is represented by a power series. But with this $K$, the function $S$ is an antiderivative of $g$, so it's not analytic unless $g$ is analytic.

A sufficient condition is that the Taylor series of $g$ centered at $(a+b)/2$ has radius of convergence greater than $(b-a)/2$. Under this  condition the series converges uniformly on $[a,b]$, which allows you to replace $g$ with its power series for the purpose of integration.